# how to pause and resume a thread in my app?

Tags: android, multithreading, resume

i am developing a game.while playing the game if the user presses the device back button i have to pause the thread and display an alert box it confirms whether the user really wants to exit or not.if the user wants to exit it simply exit the game.but the problem arise when the user does not want to exit.then i have to resume the thread. but i cannot do that..given below is my code snippet..

```
             public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

         MyGamePanel.thread.setRunning(false);
         AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Exit Alert");
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you really want to exit the Game?");
            alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                 finish();
                 return;
            } }); 
            alertDialog.setButton2("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                  dialog.cancel();
                      MyGamePanel.thread.resume();
                      MyGamePanel.thread.setRunning(true);
                return;
            }}); 
             alertDialog.show();

         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

and the given below is the thread part.

```
       @Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting game loop");

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                // update game state 
                this.gamePanel.update();
                // render state to the screen
                // draws the canvas on the panel
                this.gamePanel.render(canvas);  


            }
        } finally {
            // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
            // an inconsistent state
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }   // end finally
    }
}
```

update() and render are two functions written in MyGamePanel class.

i have tried many things but none is working..please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Usually yo do not want to use `resume` and `suspend` because they can leave the thread in an inconsistent state. The best way to do what you are trying to do is with a semaphore:

- Declare a Boolean somewhere that lets you specify if the game is paused:

  ```
  Boolean paused;
  ```
- Check this Boolean in the game loop and wait if paused:

  ```
  synchronized(paused) {
      while(paused) {
          wait();
      }
  }
  ```
- Set and unset the paused Boolean from the main thread:

  ```
  public void setPaused(boolean wantToPause) {
      synchronized(paused) {
          paused = wantToPause;
          notify();
      }
  }
  ```

This is schematic code, which does for example not treat exceptions, but you get the idea.

Comment: actually i am confused where i have to write this code...synchronysed() function in thread..rt?wat abt the other one?how can i control this on the back key event?sorry..i am not that familiar with threads.. :(

Comment: i tried to write synchronised function in my thread..but it is making error..i dnt knw where i have to write that code snippet..

Comment: the `synchronized() {}` structure is a special Java construct, not a function call. You should use it inside your game loop (in `while(running) { ... }`). Essentially when the execution reaches that point the thread will stop and wait until `paused` is false.

Comment: Maybe this documentation can help you understand Threads and synchronization: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html

Comment: my application crashes when i write the synchronized part in while(running){}.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your `MyGamePanel.thread.resume();`. Try to remove that code and see what happen.

If you think thread.resume() is the function you needed for different purpose(that you are restricted to delete it), then show us the thread.resume() function code so we can try to help you fix the resume function code.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem but i find out the solution just replace this code in the thread.

```
while (true) {
if(running){
Log.d("running", "true");
    canvas = null;
    try {
        canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
            // update game state 
            this.gamePanel.update();
            // render state to the screen
            // draws the canvas on the panel
            this.gamePanel.render(canvas);  


        }
    } finally {
        // in case of an exception the surface is not left in 
        // an inconsistent state
        if (canvas != null) {
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }`enter code here`
    }   // end finally
}
```

}

Comment: just replace this code in the thread and skip this line of code from dialog.     //GamePanel.thread.resume();